# What to do range() php function return associate array instead nummeric

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a select box like this :

```
<select class="form-control" name="quantity">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
   <option value="6">6</option>
   <option value="7">7</option>
   <option value="8">8</option>
   <option value="9">9</option>
   <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

For that I write this laravel blade code :

```
{!! Form::select('quantity', range(1,10), null , ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

But this return a select with zero-based options like this :

```
<select class="form-control" name="quantity">
   <option value="0">1</option>
   <option value="1">2</option>
   <option value="2">3</option>
   <option value="3">4</option>
   <option value="4">5</option>
   <option value="5">6</option>
   <option value="6">7</option>
   <option value="7">8</option>
   <option value="8">9</option>
   <option value="9">10</option>
</select>
```

This is because **range()** php function always return a numeric Array .is there a way to force it to return associative Array?

**Update :**
According to @Shailesh Katarmal comment , simply I should to use **selectRange** method.

Comment: `{{ Form::selectRange('number', 1, 10) }}`  try this.

Comment: Yes, that works. sorry I do not know that there is `selectRange` method

Comment: or `array_combine(range(1,10), range(1,10)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try the following code

```
{!! Form::select('quantity', array_combine(range(1, count(range(1,10))), array_values(range(1,10)) ), null , ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```